# Error in writing to multiple slaves in minimalmodbus

Tags: python, modbus, minimalmodbus

I am trying to interface with a temperature controller using Modbus RTU. I am not very familar with the topic, but I have been able to write code that can read the temperature of my three temperature controllers, but when I try to write to the three temperature controllers in sequence I get an error. The code I have been running is :

```
import minimalmodbus
import time
import serial
from datetime import datetime

minimalmodbus.BAUDRATE= 9600
minimalmodbus.PARITY = serial.PARITY_EVEN
Left = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 1,)
Middle = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 2) 
Right = minimalmodbus.Instrument('COM3', 3)  

print(Left.read_register(4096, 1))
print(Middle.read_register(4096, 1))
print(Right.read_register(4096, 1))

newTemp = 65
Ltemp = newTemp
Left.write_register(4097, Ltemp, 1)
time.sleep(.04)
Mtemp = newTemp
Middle.write_register(4097, Mtemp, 1)
time.sleep(.04)
Rtemp = newTemp
Right.write_register(4097, Rtemp, 1)
```

Again when I print the current tempearture the code does not give an error, and if I write to only one of the registers at a time (comment out the others and run them) it changes the setpoint temperature and does not throw an error.

More interestingly to me, when I do run this code, the first time I run it the setpoint of the "Left" temperature controller is changed and then an error is thrown. The next time I run the code the setpoint of the "Middle" temperature controller is changed and then an error is thrown. The last time I run the code the set point of the right temperature controller is changed with no error thown.

I tend to get different errors and I cannot really disern a pattern. They include:

```
Checksum error in rtu mode: '\x10\x01' instead of '\x01ì' . The response 
is: '\x01\x10\x10\x01' (plain response: '\x01\x10\x10\x01')

builtins.ValueError: Too short Modbus RTU response (minimum length 4 
bytes). Response: '\x02'

builtins.OSError: No communication with the instrument (no answer)
```

I have tried changing the baud rate to 4800, nothing worked when I did this. I also got similar errors changing from Modbus RTU to ascii. I was also getting the same erros when the parity was set at the defualt none. I also tried to sleep the code and change the timeout, which I think helped with the last error.

Any suggestions of what to try to stop getting these errors would be much appreciated.

Thank you

**Edit**

I tried deleting the number of decimals but still get the same error, the set point now updates so that 80 turns into 8.0, not that that's a big deal.

this is the full response I get when I run the code, now without the number of decimals:

```
19.1
19.1
21.1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/matth/Desktop/tempController.py", line 26, in <module>
    Left.write_register(4097, Ltemp)
  File "c:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 296, in write_register
    self._genericCommand(functioncode, registeraddress, value, numberOfDecimals, signed=signed)
  File "c:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 697, in _genericCommand
    payloadFromSlave = self._performCommand(functioncode, payloadToSlave)
  File "c:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 798, in _performCommand
    payloadFromSlave = _extractPayload(response, self.address, self.mode, functioncode)
  File "c:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\minimalmodbus.py", line 1032, in _extractPayload
    response))
builtins.ValueError: Too short Modbus RTU response (minimum length 4 bytes). Response: '\x01'
```

Left's temperature does change though. I still also get the instrument timeout occasionally error, but the error above seems to be the most common one. I think I will check how I wired the interface though, as I am wondering if that is the issue.

**Edit II**

I think I figured it out, I just had to increase the timeout time (I thought I already had but I guess not enough) `minimalmodbus.TIMEOUT = 3` seems to make everything work.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: So what is the output of print()? After you read the values

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing `read` before `write`, and read succeeds, then you definately have chosen right speed and parity and **don't have to change it**.

Without seeing the log of exchange, it would be difficult to guess, but I am 99% sure, the problem is `numberOfDecimals` parameter of `write_register`. It is not the number of registers, as you probably expect, it is a way to round floating number to integer.

So, change to

```
Left.write_register(4097, Ltemp)
Middle.write_register(4097, Mtemp)
Right.write_register(4097, Rtemp)
```